# How does bitbake build kernel recipes?

Tags: bitbake, openbmc

I am currently learning openBMC by analyzing the bitbake build process. I have encountered a question about how bitbake connects image recipes and kernel recipes.

Using IBM Romulus as an example:
The `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kerne`l will be set `"linux-aspeed"` in the read configuration stage

Here is a simplified hierarchy of the configuration files:

```
conf/bitbake.conf
    /home/leo/Documents/openbmc/meta-ibm/meta-romulus/conf/machine/romulus.conf
        /home/leo/Documents/openbmc/meta-aspeed/conf/machine/include/ast2500.inc
            /home/leo/Documents/openbmc/meta/conf/machine/include/soc-family.inc
            /home/leo/Documents/openbmc/meta-aspeed/conf/machine/include/aspeed.inc
```

As far as I know, the purpose of `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel` is to select a preferred kernel recipe when there are multiple providers. In the case of "linux-aspeed," the `linux-aspeed.inc` file indeed contains `PROVIDES += "virtual/kernel"`.

However, these variables alone do not determine whether the build process should proceed directly.

When compiling with bitbake obmc-phosphor-image, the process goes through the following hierarchy:

```
obmc-phosphor-image.bb
    obmc-phosphor-image.bbclass
        core-image.bbclass
            image.bbclass
```

For installing other recipes, the common method is to pass the package or recipe name to the `PACKAGE_INSTALL` variable. However, there is no information in these files about using `FEATURE_PACKAGES` to record dependencies like `DEPENDS` or `RDEPENDS:${PN} = "virtual/kernel"`.

Or specify the recipe directly via OBMC_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL.

In `image.bbclass`, there are sections like:

```
    KERNELDEPMODDEPEND ?= "virtual/kernel:do_packagedata"
    do_rootfs[depends] += " \
        makedevs-native:do_populate_sysroot virtual/fakeroot-native:do_populate_sysroot ${LDCONFIGDEPEND} \
        virtual/update-alternatives-native:do_populate_sysroot update-rc.d-native:do_populate_sysroot \
        ${KERNELDEPMODDEPEND} \"

    KERNEL_DEPLOY_DEPEND ?= "virtual/kernel:do_deploy"
    do_build[depends] += "${KERNEL_DEPLOY_DEPEND}"
```

These sections might be relevant, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.
If anyone can give me some advice, very grateful.

I tried searching virtual/kernel.

`openbmc\meta-openembedded\meta-oe\recipes-core\packagegroups\packagegroup-boot.bb` is the one that most closely matches what I think I'm thinking of, but it seems that the `core-image.bbclass` uses the `packagegroup-core-boot` not `packagegroup-boot.bb`